# Where is the Controller edit hold time setting?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Recently, I have heard a lot about the edit speed (The setting) of some Fortnite's best players.

> Controller Edit Hold Time - 0.12
>   <sub>[Best xbox one Fortnite controller settings from gronky - keengamer](https://www.keengamer.com/article/20653_best-xbox-one-fortnite-controller-settings-from-gronky)</sub>

I have looked where all of the sensitivity options are, and so have some of my friends, and they cannot find it. Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 3):

## It is right under the Builder Pro Build Instantly Setting

[image: Edit speed setting]

If you scroll down all the way in the first section on the settings page, right above feedback, it should be there.